# How to check the disk usage of /user/hadoop partition in multi-node cluster in Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hdfs

I am looking for a help from someone who can clarify my doubt. I have setup 5-node cluster environment. I have installed hadoop in linux RHEL machines.

Now I need to check the diskspace of HDFS partition /user/hadoop in every machine.How to check it.

In which partition,Logical volume..Physicallly this hdfs /user/hadoop partition is allocated.

Is it possible to do cd /user/hadoop in cluster machines.

Comment: I want to know what is /user/hadoop partition  and how to check the disk size of this partition.Internally how hadoop is allocating diskspace...

Comment: try to run df -h for disk usage and for space used by folder use du -sh /folder_name

Answer (score 0):

use **du** to get the disk usage

Usage: `hdfs dfs -du [-s] [-h] URI [URI …]`

Displays sizes of files and directories contained in the given directory or the length of a file in case its just a file.

Options:

*The -s option will result in an aggregate summary of file lengths being displayed, rather than the individual files.*

*The -h option will format file sizes in a "human-readable" fashion (e.g 64.0m instead of 67108864)*

Example:

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /user/hadoop
```

output for me:

```
24.3 M  /user/hadoop/test
```